# How to center html outputs generated by restructuredtext and how to make the table of contents larger so that the word aren't cutted anywhere?

Tags: restructuredtext

When I open the _build/html/index.html in Chrome, it is not centered in the window of the explorer. And the Table contents are too narrow. Many words are cutted.
[Here how it shouldn't be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42IzF.png)

[Here how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNRIH.png)

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It depends on the theme chosen. I took the "classic" the "Sphinxbootstrap4theme" resolved my problem.